# How to do autocomplete in listview via texbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, autocomplete, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Here i am using an autocomplete in textbox and the values are from database.It is working fine.What i need is to do this autocomplete thing in listview when i enter any value in textbox.Here is my code

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtContactsSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ServiceMethod="ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
        MinimumPrefixLength="2"
        CompletionInterval="100" EnableCaching="false" CompletionSetCount="10" 
        TargetControlID="txtContactsSearch"
        ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" FirstRowSelected = "false">
    </cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

and

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">
                    <td id="Td1" runat="server">
                        <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("regon_name") %>' />
                    </td>
                      <td id="Td2" runat="server">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("code") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DB_CGTPO_DEVEConnectionString %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT [regon_name], [code] FROM [region_test]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

and

```
 [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static List<string> ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(string prefixText, int count)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(""))
        {
            //conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager
            //        .ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "select regon_name from region_test where " +
                "regon_name like @SearchText + '%'";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefixText);
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                List<string> customers = new List<string>();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {

                        customers.Add(sdr["regon_name"].ToString());
                    }
                }
                conn.Close();
                return customers;
            }
        }
    }
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: possible duplicate of [asp.net ajax control toolkit autocomplete extender](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784707/asp-net-ajax-control-toolkit-autocomplete-extender)

Comment: Please don't post the same question twice. Try to edit your previous question. Is very unclear what you mean by "to do this autocomplete thing in listview".

Comment: i want to show the values in the listview from database when i type those values in textbox

Comment: @vani Do you have access or would you be willing to use Telerik RadTools?  If so I have a solution I can share.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you not just put the textbox inside the listview.. ?

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">
                    <td id="Td1" runat="server">
                        <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("regon_name") %>' />
                    </td>
                      <td id="Td2" runat="server">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("code") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
<tr>
 <td id="Td3" runat="server" colspan="2">
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtContactsSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ServiceMethod="ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
        MinimumPrefixLength="2"
        CompletionInterval="100" EnableCaching="false" CompletionSetCount="10" 
        TargetControlID="txtContactsSearch"
        ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" FirstRowSelected = "false">
    </cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>
 </td>
</tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DB_CGTPO_DEVEConnectionString %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT [regon_name], [code] FROM [region_test]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: no if enter any value like asp in textbox that value alone has to come in listview

Comment: like stackoverflow users -->type to fnd users autocomplete

Comment: Do you want the textbox to filter the records in the ListView?

Comment: I don't know why I was downvoted. Please provide additional information as to why this was downvoted.

Comment: could you modify the stored proc in the SQLDataSource to accept a parameter for the Region Name and then just add a control parameter from the SQL datasource to the textbox ?